# Suppose that $\{x_n\}_n$ satisfies $|x_n - x_{n+1}|\leq\frac{1}{2^n},\;\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$. Show that $\{x_n\}$ converges.

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences

One hint I was given was show that $\{x_n\}_n$ is Cauchy.
How can I do this?

Comment: Proceed inductively. What can you say about $|x_n-x_{n+m}|$ for any $m$?

Comment: Let n= 1, let n = 2, and let n = k

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

If you know that $|x_n-x_{n+1} | \leq 2^{-n}$ for every $n$, then
$$|x_n - x_{n+2}| \leq |x_n-x_{n+1}| + |x_{n+1}-x_{n+2}| \leq 2^{-n} + 2^{-(n+1)}$$

Now you can prove that $$\sum_{k=n}^{m} 2^{-k} = 2^{-m} (2^m-1) - 2^{-n}(2^n-1)= 2^{-n}-2^{-m}$$

Can you see how to proceed?

Comment: Wait shouldn't it be |$x_k$ - $x_{k+1}$| $\leq$ |$x_{k+1}$ - $x_{k+2}$|

Comment: @Brandon This uses the triangle inequality

Comment: Oooooooooooooooooooh!!!!!!!

Comment: @Brandon do you see how to proceed using the triangle inequality, the definition of Cauchy sequences, and the partial sums of the series?

Comment: I'm reviewing my Cauchy definition and partial sums again, I'll let you know if I'm good or still stuck

Comment: @Brandon I added a hint that may help